# how to send custom header in Dialogflow v2 textRequest

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using Dialogflow v2 in my Angular app for the client side and I have a requirement to send a custom http header (token) with the request to get it from the webhook for an intent. How can I send this custom header to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I made it work was by sending an HttpClient request to my firebase function to verify the authentication and from there I used the Dialogflow node SDK to do the Dialogflow related tasks, handling the webhooks by myself, instead of attaching a function in the Dialogflow intent.
This gave me the flexibility to use whatever type of authentication, intent and request handling I want, so I don't have to worry about the limited 5 seconds per webhook request as well.